# Generating lists from other lists while keeping the order

Tags: python, list

I have a list in the form of [2, 1, 4, 3].
Is there a way to produce all of the possible sequences of the list values while keeping the same order? To further clarify, I am expecting something like this:

```
[1, 4, 3, 2], 
[4, 3, 2, 1], 
[3, 2, 1, 4],
[2, 1, 4, 3]
```

I would describe the problem as a case of "Reshuffling" but keeping the order constant, or imagining each of these sequences being circular, i.e. the final element in the list then becomes the first, etc. There are many ways to visualize this, hope it makes some sense.

Comment: What should remain in the same order?

Comment: Sounds like you want all possible rotations of the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> data = [4, 3, 2, 1]
[4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> l = len(data)
>>> for i in range(l):
...     print(data[l - i:] + data[0:l - i])
...
[4, 3, 2, 1]
[1, 4, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 4, 3]
[3, 2, 1, 4]
```

Or if we want to capture them rather than print them:

```
[data[len(data)-i:] + data[0:len(data)-i] for i in range(len(data))]
```

Comment: Picked this answer for two main reasons: First, it worked and secondly I understand it. Other answers may have worked just as well but were beyond my understanding. The fault is not on the people who provided them that I don't understand, it's on me. I need to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
l = [1, 4, 3, 2]
for element in l:
   l.pop(0)
   # removes the first element
   l.append(element)
   # appends the element at the end
   print(l)
```

As I can see you want to remove the first element of the list and put it at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a deque to do something like this. Deque is a *Doubly Eneded Queue* and optimized for `pop()` and `append()` (in `O(1)` instead of `O(n)` for a list) and therefore well suited for a rotation that you are trying to do. Have a look at this [blog post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/deque-in-python/) for more information.

```py
from collections import deque
input_arr = [2, 1, 4, 3]
input_deque = deque(input_arr)

for i in range(len(input_arr)):
    input_deque.rotate(-1)
    print(list(input_deque))
```

Expected output:

```
[1, 4, 3, 2]
[4, 3, 2, 1]
[3, 2, 1, 4]
[2, 1, 4, 3]
```

#### Edit

As [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15261315/chris) commented, please keep the following in mind:

> Be aware, rotating a deque is destructive. If you wanted to gather the rotated lists into a list, you'd want to be sure to put copies of the deque into that list, otherwise you'll end up with a list with four references to the same deque in the same state
>
>         — [@Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15261315/chris)

To create a copy you can just call `copy()` on the created list which in my case would be done like this: `list(input_deque).copy()`.

Comment: Be aware, rotating a `deque` is _destructive_. If you wanted to gather the rotated lists into a list, you'd want to be sure to put _copies_ of the deque into that list, otherwise you'll end up with a list with four references to the same `deque` in the same state.

Comment: Good addition. Thanks. Edited the post to include that.